# Why would Rigidbody.AddForce not resulting in movement of my objects?

Tags: unity, physics

I'm trying to get my card objects to spread out randomly but nothing happens. I know the method is called cause I get the prints in the console for each card. But they don't move. No errors reported. The cards have a `RigidBody`.

```
public static void CardCascade ()
{
     print ("CARD CASCADE!");
     foreach (var card in Card.Cards) {
          float range = 500F;

          var x = Random.Range (-range, range);
          var y = Random.Range (-range, range);             
          card.rigidbody.AddForce (x, y, 0);
          print ("I just added force to card: X/Y " + x + y);
     }
}
```

Comment: How are your card's RigidBody setup? Do they have mass?

Comment: I checked the mass. And yes. They had plenty of it. I realized it was just too much. When i lowered it stuff started to move. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't miss the last argument to AddForce(), `ForceMode mode`.**  The default mode `ForceMode.Force` (*kg·m/s²* or *N*) works in the most physics-natural way, but you also have the option of making the addition mass-independent (`ForceMode.Acceleration`, *m/s²*), or velocity-based instead of acceleration-based (`ForceMode.Impulse`, *kg·m/s*), or both mass-independent and velocity-based (`ForceMode.VelocityChange`, *m/s*).

In general, the acceleration-based pair (`ForceMode.Force` and `ForceMode.Acceleration`) are best for over-time effects (in FixedUpdate(), as suggested by @danijar), while the velocity-based pair (`ForceMode.Impulse` and `ForceMode.VelocityChange`) are best for one-time effects (in Start(), Update(), FixedUpdate(), etc.).  And it's not like either won't work in either situation, it's just that the values you'll end up using are aligned to each situation.  *E.G. Using `ForceMode.Force` with a force of `30.0 * Time.fixedDeltaTime` for a one-time burst should work fine, but using `ForceMode.Impulse` with just `30.0` is more semantically meaningful.*

Setting the Rigidbody's `.velocity` directly is not recommended if the Rigidbody is already moving— the Rigidbody does a number of things internally that will likely cause the resulting velocity to not match what you set it to.  I suppose it's in there and settable for esoteric setups or custom physics system hacks, like setting an initial value for `velocity` within Start() in a situation where everything should be moving from the get-go.  However, the recommended way to accomplish `rigidbody.velocity += 5.0` is `rigidbody.AddForce(5.0, ForceMode.VelocityChange)`.

---

Your code looks as if it's for a card game, so if you do indeed want the cards to move at a predictable speed in a UI-ish manner, `ForceMode.VelocityChange` may be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Force makes rigid bodies accelerate, so their speed grows over time. Most physics engines reset the applied force every frame. Therefore, you need to apply force for several frames to give the bodies time to accelerate.

Another solution would be to set speed directly, instead of applying force. That would result in instant motion.